# Omniture firing multiple pixels on onlick

Tags: javascript, tracking, adobe-analytics

I am new to omniture. The omniture is already set-up for onlick but when I check Charles , it fires 2 pixels instead of 1 when I click the button. This is not the correct behavior. I tried searching for s.t1() in the code base but could not find anything. Can you give me a headstart as to where to start from.

Comment: first off, it's `s.tl` not `s.t1` as in the letter "l" not the number 1. 2nd, you will need to provide more details. e.g. the code you added to onclick tracking, and the link itself, etc. But my suspicion is that this is due to your link target vs. what you have in `s.linkDownloadFileTypes` or `s.linkInternalFilters`

Comment: For example, if you have `s.linkDownloadFileTypes='pdf';` and your link points to `href='somefile.pdf'` then omniture is going to fire its automated download tracking. Then if you have custom onclick tracking on that, then that's going to trigger as well.